# ASP.Net MVC Providing bolt-on functionality to existing web app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to have a ASP.Net MVC application as a core application and then have a seperate project containing, models, controllers and views that will compile and then copy to the core app bin directory so the core app picks this extra functionality up?

I hope you can see what I'm trying to suggest. The methods I have mentioned may not be correct but essentially have a core web app with pre-determined functionality and then on occasion add extra functionality via another project in the solution

**UPDATE:** Now using ASP.Net MVC 3 and reading [this](http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5e3f713e511b9e9b) post, the author of Portable Areas seems to think there is another way which I dont understand fully. How can achieve what I want in MVC 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may take a look at [MVCContrib Portable Areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx). It uses embedded views.